# Can I read external configurations from Redis or some aws service by spring boot application

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-data-redis, redis-cluster, spring-cloud-config-server

I am looking for a way to read external configuration by spring boot application.

Currently I am using spring-config-server and read configuration from `application.properties` by `@Value`.
I want to move to aws ECS and do not run config-server. As a result I want to remove the config-server and read configuration properties from external directly by each spring boot application.

I already checked the aws ssm parameter but the limit of parameters amount (100,000) that I can store is too small per account and region.

Can I read configuration from Redis by sprig boot application and access them by @value or other simple way? (not as a backend to config-server but dirrectly from spring boot application)

Or maybe there are other db/aws service that I can use?

Comment: Why not jus run the config-server? Thas has proven to work (in your own setup and also for many-many others). Also you can run the config server with AWS S3 as the backend (instead of git). See https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html/#_aws_s3_backend (for the full list of supported backends see https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html/#_environment_repository).

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest to keep using the [Spring Cloud Config Server](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-config). It can use several different backends for configuration like [AWS S3](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html/#_aws_s3_backend) or, as you mentioned, [Redis](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html/#_redis_backend).

Which backend you want to use, doesn't have to change the fact that you use the Spring Cloud Config Server (and client). It really makes things easier, instead of trying to reinvent the wheel yourself.

That being said instead of using a plain `@Value` you might want to look at [Type-safe Configuration Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties) to make it easier to work with properties from the `Environment`.

Comment: I want to replace the config server because I don't want to worry about upgrading, monitoring failures, etc...If there are aws service that know to do it and I can store my configurations I would prefer it.

Comment: You still need to worry about that, but then for your own custom build solution. If you don't want to use it, use the environment variables. The point of type-safe configuration still stands.